# Solaris 11.4 RBAC works for vim, not for su

Tags: permissions, solaris, su, uid

I want to access some commands as root, for a normal user.
I create the profile

```
profiles -p "privileged"

set desc="privileged profile"
add cmd=/bin/su
set euid=0
end
commit
exit
```

Then I add profile to user

```
usermod -P "privileged" myuser
```

I relogin with myuser, I did this

```
pfexec su
```

And..it ask for password!

I have tried to use uid instead of euid but nothing change.
If I try some other commands like vim, works fine, they run as root.
Why not for su?

Comment: Can you tell if it's `pfexec` or `su` asking for the password?

Comment: Is su, because pfexec don't ask password for commands